# Setting up the correct FTP user permissions

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, user-permissions, xinetd

To possibly fix an error, I was told to set the correct permissions to a user:

```
Make sure that ftp user of your repository has permissions for:
```

- change directory (cd)
- list directory (ls)
- create directory (mkdir)
- remove directory (rmdir)
- upload file (put)
- download file (get)

Can you help me to do each step please, how to set?

CentOS 6.4 (with proftpd / xinetd), user is already created named "test1234".

Comment: If you are using chroot that is set by default in proftpd then you probably don't need to do anything. Because user has all these privileges in home dir.

Comment: @ALex_hha : this was working already fine (by default), until the latest plesk upgrade to version 11.30, then there is a curl transfer permission error when trying to move a backup to the backup server and I was told to check out this list in the question. I thought already about to remove the user and add a new user, that should do the trick too, but since I was told to check out the list, I wanted to learn how to do this, setting each permission for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes that the user is chrooted into their home directory, you could try something like

```
<Directory ~user>
   <Limit DELE, MKD, RMD, ...>
     AllowUser user
   </Limit>
</Directory>
```

You can get more info at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html

P.S.
Also I will suggest to check permissions on the file system.

Comment: The main problem is a bug in Plesk with a / that causes the error, but your answer is the correct answer to my question. Thank you.